# Update command with parameters is not updating data table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

The whole night I've tried many ways BUT sql Update command with parameters is not updating data table. I am totally fade up. The execution is successful and returns 1 row affected BUT old data is not being replaced. Please help me out.

```
conn.Open();
string updateSql = "UPDATE tbl_cust SET fname=@fname, lname=@lname WHERE email=@email";  
SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateSql, conn);

UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "fname");
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "lname");
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "email");

UpdateCmd.Parameters["@fname"].Value = txtFirstName.Text;
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@lname"].Value = txtLastName.Text;
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = Session["sesEmail"].ToString();         
UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

Another method: (same result)

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Hib"].ConnectionString);
string upData = "UPDATE tbl_cust SET fname=@fname, lname=@lname, addrs=@address WHERE email=@email";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(upData, conn);
conn.Open();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addrs", address);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["sesEmail"].ToString());

int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Write("<script>alert('rows affected = " + n + "');</script>");
Response.Write("<script>alert('sesEmail = " + Session["sesEmail"].ToString() + "');</script>");
```

Comment: What's your connection string?

Comment: Beyond that, does it work if you run the same query in SSMS? And are you sure you're pointing at the right database? You don't have one for development and one for production, and you're pointing to the wrong one?

Comment: I think its your connection string, you are checking on the wrong database after running it,

Comment: no luck! same result! getting mad! It's a simple thing but not working without any known reason.

Comment: I am telling you, its your connection string... you are checking on  a different database and updating in a different database, please post your connection string here, so that I can verify this...

Comment: As mentioned, you are either checking the wrong database or Session["sesEmail"] is not what you think it is. 1 row affected means one row WAS updated. Step with debugger and see if you are looking at the correct email record.

Comment: Nothing wrong with connection string. Data is not committed. Why?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Using `AddWithValue` is a bad idea and should never be a recommendation.

Comment: Run Profiler on your database to determine the exact SQL that is being executed on your server.

Comment: Wait a second. You say "...not updating data table". You mean DataTable as in System.Data.DataTable? Running that query will not update a DataTable in memory unless you fetch the data again. I think we all assumed you were talking about the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would debug this by creating a stored procedure that accepts the parameters, then I would run the procedure manually from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). Confirm that the procedure itself, given the correct parameters, works, then call the procedure instead of inline SQL from the front end (this is a better approach anyway).

I.E.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateCustTable
@fname varchar(50),
@lname varchar (50),
@email varchar(50) 

AS

--EXEC usp_UpdateCustTable 'Joe', 'Blow', 'joe.blow@acmecompany.com'


UPDATE tbl_cust SET fname=@fname, lname=@lname WHERE email=@email
```

After you create the proc, run the commented out EXEC portion of the sample. Once you know the procedure is working, the issue can only boil down to the Session variable being empty, invalid connect string, or some related issues. Have you set a break point and monitored the code?

Let me know; I feel your pain, :-)

Comment: It's got to be something simple you're overlooking. Those can be the most frustrating! Get some sleep, and try again in the morning. :-)

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table, that is killing the update, or rolling the value back. Like an InsteadOf trigger?

Comment: Yes, I think it's rolling the value back. BUT what is InsteadOf trigger? How can I deal with it?

Comment: Just look at your triggers on the table from SSMS. Right click on all of them and disable them temporarily, then try again.

Comment: No triggers. Any other tips?

Comment: Best guess; the session variable is not what you think it is. Set break point and make sure it is being set to a different value. Alternatively, make sure you're checking the same row you expect to be updated. You may be checking the old email name. It's something simple my friend, I assure you! I hate when that happens. :-)

Answer (score 0):

And the magic is...Problem solved. Thank you, everyone. You are all very helpful. It was my very first post here and I'm so happy to see the prompt response from the expert panel. Thanks again.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

}
```